# Isn't the concept of promise as the same as callbacks?

Tags: callback, promise

it's almost a few months that i'm working with javaScript and i came to understand the meaning of callbacks and now i'm confused : Isn't the concept of promise as the same as callbacks?

```
API.one(function(err,data){
    API.two(function(err,data2){
        API.three(function(err,data3){

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: well, yes ... but no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are similar. For me promises, such as `.catch()`, `.then()`, do better with handling returns and error handling. So if you have nested callbacks to handle errors, the error may escape one callback function but it WILL be caught by a promise like `.catch()`.

```
this.myFunction(){
 $http({method: 'get',
         url: url})
     .then(function(err,results){
       console.log(results);
 };
```

Angular Example